# Initialize an Array of ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, initialization

How can I initialize an `Array` of `ArrayList<String>`?

I tried this syntax but it didn't work:

```
ArrayList<String>[] subsection = new ArrayList<String>[4];
```

Comment: ArrayList array[] = new ArrayList[4];

Comment: @SamirMangroliya it wouldn't work with generics

Answer (score 14):

you can define like this :

```
ArrayList<String>[] lists = (ArrayList<String>[])new ArrayList[10];
    lists[0] = new ArrayList<String>();
    lists[0].add("Hello");
    lists[0].add("World");
    String str1 = lists[0].get(0);
    String str2 = lists[0].get(1);
    System.out.println(str1 + " " + str2);
```

Comment: Unchecked cast: 'java.util.ArrayList[]' to 'java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>[]'

Answer (score 11):

That syntax works fine for the non-generic `ArrayList`. [(ideone)](http://ideone.com/usjoB)

But it *won't* work for the generic `ArrayList<E>`: [(ideone)](http://ideone.com/800Mw)

This code:

```
ArrayList<String>[] subsection = new ArrayList<String>[4];
```

Gives a compiler error:

```
Main.java:8: generic array creation
        ArrayList<String>[] subsection = new ArrayList<String>[4];
```

For the generic version use an `ArrayList<ArrayList<E>>`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> subsection = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Comment: But then the OP will end up with an ArrayList of ArrayLists, not with an array of ArrayLists. It is almost the same, but the are differences.

Comment: If the generic version is preferred, better use the Interface `List<List<String>> subsection = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();` for the variables type.

Comment: The point is that generics and arrays just don't play nicely together.

Answer (score 6):

Okay after comment, I thought well... your right why not.

Figured it out.

```
ArrayList[] test = new ArrayList[4];

test[3] = new ArrayList<String>();
test[3].add("HI");

System.out.println(test[3].get(0));
```

Though I will be honest, I am not really sure WHY this works.

Once you assign the first item of test as a new Collection, it will only allow all other items in the array to be that type. So you couldn't do

```
test[3] = new ArrayList<String>();
test[2] = new HashSet<String>();
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? Why *couldn't* you have an array of collections?

Comment: After Dave's comment, I figured out the OP's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Look into generics as type clarification process, you can assign typed value to a variable of raw type AND vice versa. In core generics are a shortcut for the programmers to avoid making type casting too much, which also helps to catch some logical errors at compile time. 
At the very basics ArrayList will always implicitly have items of type Object.

So

```
test[i] = new ArrayList<String>(); because test[i] has type of ArrayList.
```

The bit

```
test[3] = new ArrayList<String>();
test[2] = new HashSet<String>();
```

did not work - as was expected, because HashSet simply is not a subclass of ArrayList. Generics has nothing to do here. Strip away the generics and you'll see the obvious reason.

However,

```
test[2] = new ArrayList<String>();
test[3] = new ArrayList<HashSet>();
```

will work nicely, because both items are ArrayLists.

Hope this made sense...