# Array of arraylists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

im having trouble making an array of arraylists, heres's the code : 
              `'ArrayList<Integer>[] solucao= new ArrayList[6];'`
and using this code below:

```
           solucao[0].add(1);
            solucao[0].size();
                solucao[1].size();
                solucao[1].add(1);
            solucao[2].size();
            solucao[2].add(1);
                solucao[3].size();
                solucao[3].add(1);
            solucao[4].size();
            solucao[4].add(1);
                solucao[5].size();
                solucao[5].add(1);
            solucao[6].size();
            solucao[6].add(1);
                solucao[7].size();
                solucao[7].add(1);
```

all the calls for size return `null`. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Im looking for a data structure of `array of arraylists`, as each `array[i]` position will return me an `arraylist of integers`.

thank you

Comment: you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227201/initialize-an-array-of-arraylist to be precise ArrayList<Integer>[] solucao = (ArrayList<Integer>[])new ArrayList[10];

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize each `ArrayList` in the array.

```
ArrayList[] solucao = new ArrayList[6];
for (int i = 0; i < solucao.length; i++)
    solucao[i] = new ArrayList();
```

I actually thought you couldn't have an array of `ArrayList`. Apparently you can, but it must be non-generic. You should probably reconsider why you're doing this...

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] solucao= new ArrayList[6];
```

Should be `new ArrayList<Integer>[6]`

Note an IDE would give you a warning about this.  Next, initialize each element of the array (Java 7):

```
for(int i = 0; i < solucao.length; i++) {
    solucao[i] = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: It actually specifically shouldn't be `new ArrayList<Integer>[6]` in this case. Also, the for each loop doesn't work for assignments.

Comment: @ZongLi re. second yes you're right, bad mistake on my part. re. first, really? I should learn how templates + arrays work I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are just pointers or references. For each for them you have to create a new ArrayList object and store your data in it.

```
List[] solucao= new ArrayList[5];
for(int i=0;i<solucao.length;i++)
{
  solucao[i]  = new ArrayList();
  solucao[i].add(yourObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For store data first you have to create object.

```
ArrayList<Integer>[]  ls =  new ArrayList[7];
for (int i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
    ls[i] =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int j = 0 ; j<i ;j++){
        ls[i].add(j);   
    }
    System.out.println(ls[i].size());
}
```