# Initialize an Array of List<String> Objects

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to store 4 Lists of Strings to an array within index 0-3 and be able to check wether the index is filled (!=null) or not.

For that reason I need to initialize an Array of Type List, which fails in eclipse with message "Cannot create a generic array of List":

```
// Does not work
List<String>[] myArray = new List<String>[4];

// Does not work
List<String>[] myArray = new ArrayList<String>[4];
```

Doing it like promoted at [Convert an ArrayList to an object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745338/convert-an-arraylist-to-an-object-array) :

```
ArrayList<List<String>> myArrayList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
myArrayList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
myArrayList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
myArrayList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
myArrayList.add(new ArrayList<String>());

// Does not work
List<String>[] myArray = myArrayList.toArray(new List<String>[myArrayList.size()]);

// Does not work
List<String>[] myArray = myArrayList.toArray(new ArrayList<String [myArrayList.size()]);
```

But why is this not working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialize an Array of ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227201/initialize-an-array-of-arraylist)

Comment: Because "you cannot create a generic array" in Java. This was a design choice which has to do with the mismatch between the reifiability of array types vs. non-reifiability of generic type parameters.

Comment: only Cuck Norris can initiate Interfaces: new List<String>[myArrayList.size()]!!! :-)

Comment: @StefanBeike There's nothing wrong with an array of interface type: `List[]`.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: with "new List" I am able to create a List object???

Comment: @StefanBeike Noone here has mentioned intantiating the `List` type.

Comment: Here's a possible good [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5662447/1320072)!

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` *is generic class in Java*. You cannot create an array of generic type. It is not allowed. What you can do is create a list of generic type

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfStringList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Despite of this it does not come in my head, why Java is disallowing that.

Comment: That is going to be design choice, it causes problems with backward compatibility, type casting issues etc.

Comment: Did it help you understand?